# If $\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{2}=\frac{f(y)-a}{2}+xy$ and $f'(0)$ exists, prove that $f(x)>0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $\dfrac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{2}=\dfrac{f(y)-a}{2}+xy$ for all real $x$ and $y$. If $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f '(0)$ exists for all real permissible values of $a$ and is equal to $\sqrt{5a-1-a^2}$, prove that $f(x)$ is positive for all real $x$.

My attempt is as follows:-

Put $x=0,y=0$ in the functional equation

$$\dfrac{f(0)-f(0)}{2}=\dfrac{f(0)-a}{2}+0$$
$$f(0)=a$$

Partially differentiating functional equation with respect to $x$

$$\dfrac{f'(x+y)-f'(x)}{2}=y$$

Put $x=0$

$$f'(y)-f'(0)=2y$$

Replace $y$ with $x$

$$f'(x)-f'(0)=2x$$

Integrating both sides

$$f(x)-f'(0)x=x^2+c$$

Put $x=0$

$$f(0)=a$$
$$c=a$$

$$f(x)=x^2+x\cdot\sqrt{5a-1-a^2}+a$$

Let's find out the discriminant of this quadratic equation

$$D=-a^2+5a-1-4a$$
$$D=-a^2+a-1$$

Now quadratic equation $D=-a^2+a-1$ is always negative because its discriminant $D'=1-4=-3$ is less than zero and leading coefficient is negative.

Hence $D<0$ and leading coefficient of $f(x)=x^2+x\cdot\sqrt{5a-1-a^2}+a$ is positive, which indicates $f(x)$ is always positive.

Is this the right way of solving it? I doubt it as I have not used the fact that $f'(0)$ exist for all permissible values of $a$.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. The condition that $f'(0)$ exists is just to guarantee that $5a-1-a^2\ge 0$, so the square root is a (nonnegative) real number.

Comment: @quasi, In my proof, I used partial derivative and in that, after differentiating partially, I made $x=0$, and then replaced $y$ with $x$. I read this method in some text book but didn't understand why we do that? can you help with that?

Comment: If something is true for all real $y$ (with $x$ not mentioned), then $y$ could be renamed as $x$ (in this context, $y$ is just a dummy variable).

Comment: @quasi, but $y$ is not a variable right, its a constant, so how can we replace a constant with variable as constant would be having one particular value. Sorry if it looks stupid?

Comment: But it's an _arbitrary_ constant, so qualifies as an unknown. In other words, the relation in question holds for _any_ fixed value of $y$, so holds for _all_ values of $y$.

Comment: For example, to prove that for the function $f(x)=x^2$ we have $f'(x)=2x$, one shows that for any fixed constant $x_0$, we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=2x_0$$
hence $f'(x_0)=2x_0$. But then since $x_0$ was arbitrary, we can regard it as an unknown, and then rename it as $x$.

Comment: ok, but I didn't understand one thing, after partial differentiation, why we made $x=0$, why we can't make $y$ as $0$

Comment: You _can_ put $y=0$, but try it -- it doesn't yield any new information.